# I need to validate email using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, boolean, logic

The conditions for the valid emails are

1.It doesn't contain spaces,

2.It contains the @ symbol,

3.After @, there's a dot.

and Note that dots may also occur before @, and in a correct address a dot shouldn't stand immediately after @.

I have tried and written the below code.

```
def check_email(string):
    a = ' ' in string
    r = 0
    if a != False:
        b = "@" in string
        if b == True:
            c = "@." in string
            if c == True:
                r = False
            else:
                r = True    
        else:
            r = False    
    else:
        r = False
    return r
a = input("Enter your email :")
print(check_email(a))
```

Now i am unable to check the error.

the test sample i.e

My e-mail is: this@example.com

Correct output:
False

My code output:
True

Comment: Why have you tagged this with "java" if you want to use Python?

Comment: why is 'this@example.com' not a valid email? shouldn't the correct output here be `True`?

Comment: @alaniwi tag is removed now .

Comment: @L.Grozinger thats why i m here bro

Comment: so should 'Correct output: False' should be 'Correct output: True'?

Comment: unrelated to the solution, but `if a != False:` is a classic...

Comment: @L.Grozinger the correct output is ```False```

Comment: @CODING WITH TIWARI In that case can you clarify why 'this@example.com' does not meet your requirements as stated in the question?

Comment: no problem, i think, as it turns out, it is related to your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose a regex based check, but if you want to use just the basic string functions, here are the requested 3 checks (no space; contains @; contains a dot after @, but not immediately after @). It allows nonsense like `@@?.`, a regex is really much better.

```
def check_email(string):
    if ' ' in string:
        return False
    if "@" not in string:
         return False
    name, domain = string.split('@', 1)
    if '.' not in domain[1:]:
        return False
    return True
```

Note that a function is not limited to one return at its end. Look how the code becomes readable when a result is returned as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

`a != False` evaluates to `True` if `a` is `True` and `False` if `a` is `False`. In other words, it evaluates to `a`.

With that in mind, the error in your code becomes more obvious: if there is not a space in `string`, then `a` will be `False`, the `else` part of your first `if` statement will set `r = False` and the function returns.

Avoiding comparisons of boolean literals to boolean variables in your `if` conditions will make your code much clearer and help spot these kind of problems. It is also entirely unnecessary to do so; `if a != False:` for example, is the same thing as `if a:`, but it is much clearer what the second one is doing. Similarly, `if c == True` is the same as `if c:`.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
def check_email(string):
    a = ' ' in string
    r = 0
    if not a:
        b = "@" in string
        if b:
            c = "@." in string
            if c:
                r = False
            else:
                r = True    
        else:
            r = False    
    else:
        r = False
    return r
a = input("Enter your email :")
print(check_email(a))
```

However, it will be better for you in the long run if you consider solutions like using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html), or as suggested in another answer, [third-party packages](https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/). In particular, it will be hard to meet the 3rd condition in the question in an elegant way using the approach you've used so far.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using regular expressions:

```
import re
def email_is_correct(email):
    return bool(re.fullmatch("[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]+", email)) and True
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def check_email(string):
    return string.find(" ") == -1 and string.find("@") != -1 and string.find("@.") == -1 and string.find(".", string.find("@")) != -1
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks